# oracle, trying to create a procedure which create a user

Tags: oracle

I try to create this procedure (as a system), which takes 2 parameters, 
username and password, and create a user according to them:

```
create or replace procedure procedure_create_client 
( user_name IN varchar2 , u_password IN varchar2 )  IS

tmp_query varchar(150);
user_name_upper varchar(30) := UPPER(user_name) ;

BEGIN

    tmp_query := 'create user C##' || user_name_upper || ' identified by ' || u_password ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( tmp_query );

    tmp_query := 'grant create session to ' || user_name_upper ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( tmp_query );

END ;
```

The problem is, when I try to execute this procedure (as a system),
I got this error:

> Error report: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges ORA-06512: at
>   "SYSTEM.PROCEDURE_CREATE_CLIENT", line 9 ORA-06512: at line 1
>   01031. 00000 -  "insufficient privileges"
>   *Cause:    An attempt was made to change the current username or password
>              without the appropriate privilege. This error also occurs if
>              attempting to install a database without the necessary operating
>              system privileges.
>              When Trusted Oracle is configure in DBMS MAC, this error may occur
>              if the user was granted the necessary privilege at a higher label
>              than the current login.
>   *Action:   Ask the database administrator to perform the operation or grant
>              the required privileges.
>              For Trusted Oracle users getting this error although granted the
>              the appropriate privilege at a higher label, ask the database
>              administrator to regrant the privilege at the appropriate label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider avoiding SYS (and SYSTEM) for tasks other than database maintenance; perhaps you'd rather create your own user, let's call it MYDBA and grant it DBA role.

Something like that is what I did in the following example: I created a new user, SCOTT, and granted it only privileges to create another users.  GRANT CREATE SESSION has additional WITH ADMIN OPTION, otherwise SCOTT wouldn't be able to grant CREATE SESSION to users it creates via a procedure.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL> create user scott identified by tiger quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to scott with admin option;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create procedure to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create user to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Now, connected as newly created SCOTT user, create a procedure (copy/paste of your code, with additional "C##" in line 10) and execute it in order to create yet another user, MIKE:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> create or replace procedure procedure_create_client
  2    (user_name IN varchar2 , u_password IN varchar2 )
  3  IS
  4    tmp_query varchar(150);
  5    user_name_upper varchar(30) := UPPER(user_name) ;
  6  BEGIN
  7    tmp_query := 'create user C##' || user_name_upper || ' identified by ' || u_password;
  8    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( tmp_query );
  9
 10    tmp_query := 'grant create session to C##' || user_name_upper ;
 11    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( tmp_query );
 12  END;
 13  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec procedure_create_client('mike', 'lion');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Fine; C## seems to be created. Let's connect:

```
SQL> connect c##mike/lion@xe
Connected.
SQL>
```

Looks all right, doesn't it? Though, poor C##mike doesn't have any privileges but CREATE SESSION, but that's what you planned for it.

Comment: I want to thank you so much for your respone..
the compile for procedure work correctly without any problem.
but I have a small problem:
when I try to execute it I got the error message:

Comment: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "PROCEDURE" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
The symbol "PROCEDURE" was ignored.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: You should post EXACTLY what you ran, just like I did. A blind guess: did you forget to put underline between PROCEDURE and CREATE_CLIENT?

Comment: look I try to run this :
execute procedure procedure_create_client('test', 'test123');

Comment: Remove the first PROCEDURE word

Comment: I remove it, but unfortunately I obtain the same error posted in the question.

Comment: even I grant all privileges to user with admin option !!
but it's not working.

Comment: I provided full, working example. You should simply follow my steps.

Comment: which version of oracle your have ?
I have 12c

Comment: It is 11g Express Edition, 11.2.0.2.0. Nonetheless, that procedure should work on 12c as well (at least, I strongly believe so).

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that the user who you intend to run your script with does not have authority to change username and password for the current user. If the current user's username is passed to the procedure, then the problem is that you are not granted the necessary privilege to change your own username or password. If you try to create another user, then the error message seems to be buggy, but you still have a privilege problem. You need to review your privileges and check them against the privileges you need to create a user.

Comment: and what is the solution ?
if I want to grant  a user the privileges "create user"
?

Comment: @user9152856 your user needs to have the create user system privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the missing privilege is because you granted it by a ROLE. In a PL/SQL block you have only privileges which are applied directly. You must use  `grant create user to...`. Granting role (e.g. `grant DBA to...`  has no effect inside the procedure.